# Mathematica cannot NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to evaluate a numerical integral:

```
 NIntegrate[
 Exp[-2*Pi*I*Integrate[EllipticTheta[3, (-Pi)*u, 0.4], {u, 0, t}]]*
  Exp[2*Pi*I*t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Then, error occurs, which says that the integral has evaluated to non-numerical values.

[image]

How can I fix this problem? I think the problem occurs because of nested integration.

Comment: I think it's because you're using `Integrate` (not `NIntegrate`) in the inner one. Also, you could use just one `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 3):

the inner integral does not evaluate using `Integrate`.

And even if you use `NIntegrate` on it, you can not integrate it, since the inner integral upper limit is $t$ and this is not defined when the inner integral is being evaluated.

One way is to change the second integration to use `{x,0,t}` and pass in `t` as parameter and use `t` now in the inner integral. Something like

```
foo[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-2*Pi*I*NIntegrate[EllipticTheta[3, -Pi*u, 0.4], {u, 0, t}]]*
   Exp[2*Pi*I*x], {x, 0, t}]
```

So now for each $t$ value you can integrate the above.

```
foo[.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
foo[.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc..

Comment: Well.. is your modified integral same as the original one?

Comment: I think so. But if you do not think it is the same, I'll be happy to delete this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[t_?NumericQ] := Exp[2*Pi*I*t]*Exp[-2*Pi*I*
    NIntegrate[EllipticTheta[3, (-Pi)*u, 2/5], {u, 0, t},
     WorkingPrecision -> 20]]

ReImPlot[int[t], {t, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> "ReIm"]
```

[image]

```
y = NIntegrate[int[t], {t, 0, 1}]

(* 0.846147 *)

y == NIntegrate[Re[int[t]], {t, 0, 1}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
 elli = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == EllipticTheta[3, (-Pi)*t, 4/10],y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 1}] 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-2*Pi*I*elli[t]]*Exp[2*Pi*I*t], {t, 0, 1}]
 (*0.846147 - 3.63999*10^-7 I*)
```

which confirms @BobHanlon's solution